# Django ORM query, distinct values and join the same table

Tags: mysql, django

I would like to return all columns based on distinct values from column `site` where `hide = 0` and order it by date from `created`. I'm aware that `distinct()` call with specified field names is currently supported only by PostgresSQL but I'm running MySQL. I've got a working SQL query (it's probably not very efficient) but not sure how to convert it to Django ORM.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Results(models.Model):
    user_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(unpack_ipv4=True)
    site_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(unpack_ipv4=True)
    site = models.URLField()
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hide = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site
```

**Table structure:**

```
mysql > SHOW CREATE TABLE results\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: results
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `results` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_ip` char(39) NOT NULL,
  `site_ip` char(39) NOT NULL,
  `site` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `hide` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=836 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT site, MAX(created) created 
    FROM results 
    GROUP BY site 
    ORDER BY MAX(created) DESC 
    LIMIT 10
) _d 
JOIN results USING (site, created) 
ORDER BY _d.created DESC
```

Comment: if you need orm then you need to post models.py with the fields

Comment: @Exprator added my `models.py`

Comment: what is hget_scan ?? do you have a model for that?

Comment: You can ignore that, that was my testing. I just updated table name to `results` so it's less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There is module that allows you to group Django models and still work with a QuerySet in the result: https://github.com/kako-nawao/django-group-by

For example:

```
from django_group_by import GroupByMixin

class ResultsQuerySet(QuerySet, GroupByMixin):
    pass

class Results(Model):
    # your model
```

---

```
class GroupedResultsListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'xxx/results.html'
    model = Results

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Results.objects.group_by('site').annotate(
            max_created=Max('created')).order_by(
            'created').distinct()
        # order by 'max_created' might also work
```

'xxx/results.html'

```
<ul>
{% for result in object_list %}
    <li>
        <h2>{{ result.site }}</td>
        <p>{{ result.max_created }}</p>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The difference to the `annotate`/`aggregate` basic Django queries is the use of the attributes of a related field, e.g. `result.site`. You can also group by several attributes in one query, e.g.

```
Results.objects.group_by('site', 'user_ip')
```

If you need the PKs of the instances that have been grouped together, add the following annotation:

```
.annotate(pks=ArrayAgg('id'))
```

NOTE: `ArrayAgg` is a Postgres specific function, available from Django 1.9 onwards: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg

Comment: Is there a way to do this without external modules?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a workaround but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it because this requires two database hits:

```
views.py

recent_results_ids = []
[recent_results_ids.append(i.id) for i in Results.objects.raw('SELECT MAX(id) id FROM results WHERE hide = 0 GROUP BY site ORDER BY MAX(created) DESC LIMIT 10')]
recent_results = Results.objects.filter(id__in=recent_results_ids).order_by('-id')
```